# Control Visual Studio plugins from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to control the addins Visual Studio 2008 loads via the command line?
I am looking for a way to load my DevExpress plug in when I am working with VB or C# and alternatively load Visual Assist X when I am working on a c++ project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a direct answer but you can disable Visual Assist X either via the menu (VAssistX | Enable/Disable ) or via the command VAssistX.EnableDisable (both of these toggle between on and off).  Alternatively, you can add .cs and .vb file extensions to the "Extension to ignore" list in Visual Assist Options | Projects | File Handling.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to access the command line from a plugin. I think the only option, if you really want this and the plugin doesn't support it out of the box, is the write your own plugin. To do this, just read Environment.CommandLine from the OnConnection method.